# Unable to send the value extracted from Json extractor as a body parameter for another http request in different thread in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I am trying to fetch a value from a json response using Json extractor and use that value as a body parameter for the next http request which is in another thread group.

I am able to fetch the value in debug sampler but when i use the solutions provided on the net to pass the value then nothing is getting picked.

Also my 1st request accepts the body in form-data format and the 2nd accepts the datavin raw format.

Attaching the screenshots below for better understanding:

drs_id captured in debug sampler of the 1st thread group:
[DRS captured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvvhI.jpg)

Json extractor settings in the 1st thread group:
[Json extractor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ujk11.jpg)

[Bean shell post processor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Szwa.jpg)

Tried two ways to get the value in the 2nd thread group in the body:
[Body of the 2nd request in another thread group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Re1FM.jpg)

In the request body drs_id is not getting picked up
[request body is not getting the value of drs_id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jodcN.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest instead of `Beanshell postporcesser` use `Beanshell Assertion`. With your example I am able to pass it,

DRS_ID Fetched

[image]

Set is as Property Variable in Beanshell Assertion

[image]

Pass the value in second thread group,
[image]

[image]

Using you method,

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Be aware of [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules)

If you add JSON Extractor and Beanshell PostProcessor at the same level as 1 or more Samplers - the PostProcessors will be executed **after each sampler**

In your situation:

1. JSON Extractor is executed after `DRS Creation` sampler - here the variable is extracted and set
2. Then JSON Extractor is executed after **Debug Sampler**, there is no match found hence you're getting default empty value

So you need to either remove/disable the Debug Sampler or put your JSON Extractor and Beanshell PostProcessor to be the direct children of the `DRS Creation` sampler

---

Also be aware that [starting from JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so it worth considering migrating. More information: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)